AI search problem solving with infinite state spaces: when do algorithms halt?
In classical artificial intelligence, there is an area of ​​problem solving by search. And there are several search algorithms, such as: Breadth-first search (BFS), Depth-first search (DFS), Iterative-deepening search (IDS), Uniform cost search (UCS), etc.
We consider that Depth-first search (DFS) is not complete, in infinite state spaces, even if the solution exists and can be found with a finite number of node expansions. That's the reason for introducing depth-first search (DFS) as a solution to this problem.
But, in this case, I was thinking the following, assuming that the graph starting from the initial node is infinite. And the objective node cannot be accessed from the initial state (we have a disconnected graph). In this case, the algorithm will not return failure, because it will always be able to expand the frontier. But soon after thinking about this issue, I realized that this problem occurs with all these search algorithms I mentioned. Because the classic criterion for returning failure is when the border is empty, and the solution has not yet been found, according to this book:
Is my reasoning correct?

A common heuristic on a search that would go on forever is to return the best found so far after a certain amount of wall clock time (or some other measure of computational effort).
